# Is it possible to 'Pin to taskbar' using Inno Setup?

Tags: taskbar

I am using the Inno Setup to package the Windows installer, during the install process，I need to provide options for the user to create a desktop shortcut and pin the shortcut in the taskbar.

I can create the desktop shortcut like this:

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon";
Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}";
GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}";
Flags: checkablealone，
```

However, I can not find a way to pin the shortcut in the taskbar.

I have done some preliminary research but have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

See solution at your problem in the post at https://switch-case.com/51148020

This is a include script

function PinAppTo(const FileName: string; PinDest: TPinDest): Boolean;